# Equivalent of PostgreSQL's array_agg in Oracle XE 11.2

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, oracle11gr2, array-agg

I have a Oracle 11g XE database and I have a query the result set:

```
ID   Category
1    Cat1
1    Cat2
2    Cat3
2    Cat4
```

I want to get distinct id's with all related categories in same row as comma separated like this

```
ID   Categories
1    Cat1,Cat2
2    Cat3,Cat4
```

I was using Postgres before and `array_agg` helped me there. How can I get same result in Oracle 11g XE?

Comment: tl;dr - `LISTAGG()` was added in 11g and will give you the result set you need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you are  using it in a stored procedure to save the output as an array(or collection), a query with `LISTAGG` should be sufficient and gives the same output.

```
select ID , LISTAGG(Category,',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ID ) Categories
FROM yourtable GROUP BY ID;
```

In oracle, we do not have have a straightforward conversion function like `array_agg`. However, you can create a user-defined collection type, then use `CAST` and `COLLECT` functions to convert it to a `NESTED TABLE` to get the same desired output.

Firstly, create a collection `TYPE`.

```
create or replace TYPE categorytype as TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
```

Now, running this query is equivalent to using `string_agg` or `LISTAGG`, although `categories` is an array or **collection**, rather than a string.

```
select id, CAST ( COLLECT(Category) as categorytype ) categories
FROM yourtable group by id;

| ID | CATEGORIES |
|----|------------|
|  1 |  Cat1,Cat2 |
|  2 |  Cat3,Cat4 |
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ef7b/3)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Your suggestion worked for me.

Comment: i have added below two record to the table:    INTO yourtable (ID, Category)
         VALUES (2, 'Cat4')
    INTO yourtable (ID, Category)
         VALUES (2, 'Cat4') when i use listagg query i got 2 Cat3,Cat4,Cat4i,Cat4 result. How can i avode duplicate values in listagg?

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has a function `listagg()` which is pretty close to Postgres's `string_agg()`.  Both seem to do what you want to do.

However, `array_agg()` creates an array using a SQL expression.  I don't think Oracle supports arrays as native types in SQL statements (although arrays are part of PL/SQL).  Hence there is no equivalent.