# Is there any analogue of ARRAY_AGG PostgreSQL function in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How in can I return an array in Oracle similar to PostgreSQL's `ARRAY_AGG` function?

```
SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(EMAIL)
FROM
    EMPLOYEES
WHERE
    EMAIL IS NOT NULL
AND
    ORGANIZATION_ID IN (27623,27734)
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Equivalent of PostgreSQL's array\_agg in Oracle XE 11.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47856440/equivalent-of-postgresqls-array-agg-in-oracle-xe-11-2)

Comment: Well, if I use `LISTAGG` function which is recommended in this post it raise error: `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long`.  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Google the error  : you will get several other alternatives

Comment: In Google I found recommendation to use `XMLAGG` function but I don't know it is best practice in that case. I use `RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, EMAIL, ',').EXTRACT('//TEXT()')).GetClobVal(), ',') EMAILS` and it works.

Comment: You have 2 options, either completely rethink the way you need to store and use such large data, i.e. avoiding concatenation altogether.  If it isn't possible then go with the alternative ( like xmlagg, user defined functions using clob ,etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `LISTAGG()`

```
SELECT
    LISTAGG(EMAIL) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EMAIL) as email
FROM
    EMPLOYEES
WHERE
    EMAIL IS NOT NULL
AND
    ORGANIZATION_ID IN (27623,27734)
```

Comment: Hello! I just add this part to your code `LISTAGG(EMAIL, ',')`. It works if result is not huge. If result if huge I have such error: `ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long`. Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek, you can LISTAGG(Desc, ' ' ON OVERFLOW TRUNCATE ) but not sure whether it will solve your problem or not

Comment: Finally, I decided to use `XMLAGG` function like that `RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, EMAIL, ',').EXTRACT('//TEXT()')).GetClobVal(), ',') EMAILS`. In my case it return list of emails separated by comma for huge list. For example I have such result `NNogerbek@gmail.com,BKim@gmail.com`. Is it possible to return such result `'NNogerbek@gmail.com','BKim@gmail.com'`. I want to add `'` symbol at start and end of each email. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: you can use concat() for that - after concating u passed it to XMLAGG function

Comment: In what part of my code I need to put `concat` function. I am little bit confused.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek concat('''',email,'''')

Comment: I have such error `ORA-00909 invalid number of arguments concat` ;(

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek you can check this - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8c6251ccae8ec1b5886fedf3ed1b20d9

Comment: Thank you! I tested your code. It return me strange result: `&apos;NNogerbek@gmail.com&apos;,&apos;BKim@gmail.com&apos;`. I don't know why instead of `'` symbol it return me `&apos;`. Do you have any ideas about that?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek, no actually I don't have any idea - but if I found anything I'll let u know

Comment: I found solution. You need to use `utl_i18n.unescape_reference(***)`.